# JavaScript REGEX extend `/pattern/` with custom functions

Tags: javascript, regex

I know I can do this...

```
RegExp.prototype.xtend = function(){ console.log(123) }
y = new RegExp(/pattern/)
y.xtend()
```

I want to extend regex patterns in this format: `/pattern/`, so I can do...

```
/pattern/.xtend()
```

---

Edit: It was a problem with syntax

Turns out it was a missing semi-colon. I need a semi-colon before the regex pattern otherwise it gives syntax error.

Thanks for all the comments. Works great now.

Comment: And what's the problem? This works for me in Chrome and FF11

Comment: You do have to define xtend() in the prototype as you did at the top, but it can be called as `/pattern/.xtend()`

Comment: Works perfectly in FF11.

Comment: `/asd/` is actually just a shortcut for `new RegExp('asd')`, so there is no real difference.

Comment: Please do post an answer and accept it just so that this one does not attract views as "not yet answered". Or if any of the others *that helped in the comments* (such as @Michael) post one, accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a missing semi-colon. I need a semi-colon before the regex pattern otherwise it gives syntax error.

I was running this in Firebug console, which automatically returns the value of the last line... but because there is no semi-colon after the third line, and the fourth starts with a regex, it was getting an error.

```
RegExp.prototype.xtend = function(){ console.log(123) }
y = new RegExp(/pattern/)
y.xtend()
/pattern/.xtend()
```

Adding the semi-colon solves the problem...

```
RegExp.prototype.xtend = function(){ console.log(123) }
y = new RegExp(/pattern/)
y.xtend(); // <~~ this semi-colon fixes the issue
/pattern/.xtend()
```

Thanks for all the comments. Works great now.